# How to recovery Ubuntu 12.04 just from the .iso file, without CD-ROM

Tags: ubuntu, recovery

My computer does not have a CD-ROM, so I can not recovery the Ubuntu 12.04 from CD setup disk. I have downloaded the DVD ISO file from Ubuntu website, How can I mount the ISO file, and recovery the system files or make the DVD ISO to be the update source ? The Ubuntu 12.04 can not get the Internet. Thanks.

Comment: @Blender, thanks, but I have no USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have installed GRUB 2,  [Grub2/ISOBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) may helps.  it permits the user to boot and install Ubuntu directly from an ISO on the hard drive

Comment: Thank you. I enter into the recovery mode, then do 'dkpg'，some broken packages are repaired.